# fill an array with json when user click on a button

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have to let user make a choice between products (`p1, p2,...`) with a react native picker (on android) and then he had to set quantity of chosen product with a TextInput, and then I have to show him after clicking `Add` button which product he chose, and after each `Add` click a new item of product and his quantity is shown :

[image]

I don't know how to set data (productId and quantity) in an array or JSON

this is a part of code:

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      valueP: '',
      quantity: '',
    }}
...
<View style={Styles.type12Container}>
                  <View style={Styles.inputContainer}>
                    <Picker
                      value={this.state.valueP}
                      style={Styles.picker}
                      mode= "dropdown"
                      prompt= "XXX"
                      selectedValue = {this.state.valueP}
                      onValueChange = {(val) => { this.setState({valueP: val}}}>
                      <Picker.Item label="P 1" value="1" />
                      <Picker.Item label="P 2" value="2"/>
                      <Picker.Item label="P 3" value="3" />

                    </Picker>
                  </View>
                  <View style={Styles.inputContainer}>
                  <TextInput
                    value={this.state.quantity}
                    style={Styles.inputStyle}
                    onChangeText={(val) => this.setState({quantity: val})}
                  />
                  </View>

                  <View style={Styles.button1Container}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={this.addConv}
                    style={Styles.buttonAdd}>
                      <Text style={Styles.button1Text}>Add</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>

                  <View style={Styles.output}>
                    <View>
                      <Text style={Styles.button1Text}>products and quantity items</Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>
              </View>
```

can you please suggest me a solution or a similar example

Comment: Please post your current code so that we can work with it. Otherwise you'll only get general answers which may not apply to your current code.

Comment: I will add it in an answer to my post

Comment: Please provide block of code which you have tried, also try to add more technical detail

Comment: @zedArt that's not where it's supposed to go, you should add it to your question.

Comment: its okey now, it was edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but my guess is that you are struggling to render a list of items added by the user. In order to do that you need to store them somewhere - for simplicity's sake let's store them in the component's state.

You did not provide what `this.addConv` does, but I will assume that it's implementation is correct.

```
...
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    ...,
    items = []
  }
}
...
this.addConv = () => {
  const newItem = {
    id: this.state.valueP,
    quantity: this.state.quantity
  };
  this.setState(state => ({
    items: state.items.concat([newItem])
  }));
}
...
render() {
...
<View style={Styles.output}>
  <View>
    {this.state.items.map(item => (
      <Text style={Styles.button1Text}>{this.getProductName(item.id)} - {item.quantity}</Text> // or whatever you want to do with this
    ))}
  </View>
</View>
...
```

Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Im asking for how to add data (product and quantity) to each item. Actually what doSomethingWithTheData(event) do ? I don't not how get this data and store it in item5[ ]

Comment: Well, that depends on what you want to render. Your component have two state fields: `quantity` and rather enigmatic `valueP`. I assume you want to display the item's information based on that. However `valueP` is just a string representing a number, nothing meaningful.

Comment: yes valueP get value from picker, but it change everytime user chose another product it will change so I don't have to show it

Comment: I've edited my answer with a generic example of what you can do that with the data. `this.getProductName` assumes that you don't want to display just a number, but the actual name of the product, based on `valueP`.

Comment: Once the user click's 'Add', the item is added to the state with the currently chosen values, so later changes won't affect what's shown for this specific item. I hope I get you right.

Comment: Wait a second, now I think I know what you mean. You want to show the quantities of all items (starting with 0) and upon clicking 'Add' modify (increment) the quantity of the selected one. Is that right?

Comment: no no, first time there is no item ! when user click ADD first item is shown with product chosen in picker and quantity inserted in TextInput (both by the user ) and every time he chose a product with a quantity and he click ADD a new item is shown

Comment: It's okey your code works fine, I just had to set ...<Text>{item.id} - {item.quantity}</Text>... THANK YOU A LOT